# PHP and wordpress: Sorting Menu items

Tags: wordpress, sorting, menuitem

I'm working on a wordpress site, customizing the menu.  I'm no php whiz, and I want the menu to sort according to the numerical order, not desc alphabetically.

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul> 
  <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=post_title&sort_order=desc&title_li=&depth=1&')?>
  </ul> 
</div><!-- end id:navigation -->
```

Any ideas how I do this?  I've tried editing the above code, but I just lose the menu altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
wp_list_pages('sort_column=ID&sort_order=desc&title_li=&depth=1&');
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using WordPress 3.0 new Menu feature ... this would allow the admin to create a custom menu, sort it via drag and drop and in your theme/page you can call a [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function to display the menu.